# Adding all the values that has same class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

Here is my html

```
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_5" value="35">
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_6" value="15">
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_7" value="25">
```

I am trying to add all the values that has the same class name tt

So i am doing like this

```
$('.tt').each(function(i, obj) {
    var oo = obj;
    console.log(oo)
});
```

When i do `console.log(00)`

It prints

```
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_5" value="35">
```

But when I try to do

```
console.log(oo.val())
```

It is showing `undefined` How can I get the value ?

Am using jQuery

Comment: `oo` shouldn't be `obj` and did you tried `this.value`/`oo.value` or `$(oo).val()`?

Comment: @Satpal I updated it, actually i am doing this `var oo = obj;`

Comment: `obj` passed to function is dom element and no longer a jQuery object. You can either use `obj.value` or convert it to jQuery object `$(obj).val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the correct object name. The second argument of callback inside `each` points to the object, using that you can access the value of input tags.

```js
$('.tt').each(function(i, o) {
    console.log($(o).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_5" value="35">
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_6" value="15">
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_7" value="25">
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var total = 0;
$('.tt').each(function(){
  console.log("Current Value:", $(this).attr('value'));
  total += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
});

console.log("Total: ",total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_5" value="35">
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_6" value="15">
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_7" value="25">
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the value of the *element*

```
var total = 0;
$('.tt').each(function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.value)//value is printed
    total += Number(obj.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log the values do this:

```
$('.tt').each(function(i, obj) {
    var value = $( obj ).val();

    console.log( value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this function adds up all the values and returns the sum.

```js
function getSum() {
   var total = 0;
   $('.tt').each(function(i, obj) {   
      total += Number(obj.value);
   });

   return total;
}

console.log(getSum());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_5" value="35">
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_6" value="15">
<input type="hidden" class="tt to_7" value="25">
```